# Crontab changing the character encoding on a jar execution

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup, cron

I have a webcrawling software, written in Java, that goes through any given website, and collects data. So far, so good. I use the JSoup API for ease, but that's irrelevant. My problem lies in encoding.

When I run the Jar file on the server (using java -jar Crawler.jar), it captures data perfectly - including international accentuation, like á, é, and so on, so forth. HOWEVER... When I schedule it through crontab, it just screws up every non-basic character! What could be the problem here? I'm really at a loss, an answer would truly save my skin.

EDIT - A friend suggested I checked out the locale running on Cron, using this code:

```
    */1 * * * * locale > /home/user/locale.ouput
```

I did, and it seems that crontab is using a POSIX locale, as opposed to the system settings, that are UTF-8. I'll look on how to change it to UTF-8. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Please see my answer. That is how you set the locale. The variable is "lang" but that is the relevant part of locale for your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the character encoding explicitly whenever you convert bytes to or from characters. For example, in the String constructor, String.getBytes(), InputStreamReader constructor, etc.

If that isn't enough, try setting the LANG environment variable to a different value inside crontab before it launches Java. For example, you could use

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Specifically, as a rule you want to be explicit with ALL environmental variables in a cron job, as the values that they start with tend to be extremely limited. Make no assumptions about environment variables in cron tasks, set them all appropriately in the script.

Comment: This helped me. I didn't really catch that part about setting the variable INSIDE cron, though. What I did was editing the /etc/environment file, and adding LANG=pt_BR.UTF8 (en_US didn't work, for some reason!) to it, and then restarting the cron service. That did the trick.

It would be better to set the variable only for Java, though, since other things run on the system, and changing the global setting for every one of them might cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I assume if you are testing this on a production server you are using ssh or similar to run it remotely and are viewing the results on a terminal emulator.

Java is obviously unicode so this sounds like a unicode-ascii issue.  If the server is writing these to a text file, its possible that there is some sort of discrepancy between the output encoding and how it is being rendered on the terminal.

If you have it set up to write to a file, what I would do is first, try a different terminal emulator to make sure that the text is not being garbled by a non-unicode emulator.  If thats not the problem, you may want to double check the character encoding of the file itself and make sure that there isn't some sort of hidden issue with the software.

Ideally, you would just open up a tty on the physical server and view the output and character encoding that way but this isn't always convenient or possible.

I've had similar issues with garbled text and it almost always comes down to an issue with the terminal emulator.